# Unable to forget certain Wi-Fi networks

Tags: wi-fi

When I activate the Wi-Fi on my Android device, I can see some networks that I never saved, and that cannot be forgotten.

What are those, and how can I forget them?

Comment: Hi, those are not realistically "Saved" those are the "Wifi Hotspots" that your device could possibly connect to.  You can only "FORGET" a wifi connection when you had a connection made on it before. Hope this is clear.

Comment: Thank you I am over 40 and therefore technologically challenged

Comment: If it says under the name of the WiFi network "not in range" then you can usually long press on them and "forget" but there are WiFi networks that you can't remove for some reason, like in my phone there is one called attWIFI that one came with my phone and i can't remove it

Comment: @JimSteven I believe that this comment should be made into an answer.